# São Componentes da API no pacote aws?

Tags: java, awt

Tenho a seguinte questão. E sim, nela consta "aws" ao invés de "awt", mas penso que o correto seria "awt".

> São Componentes da API no pacote aws?
>
> I - Panel
>
> II - Label
>
> III - Windows
>
> IV - Checkbox
>
> V - TextField
>
> ---
>
> A - Apenas I
>
> B - Apenas I, II, IV, V
>
> C - Apenas I e II
>
> D - Apenas I e IV
>
> E - Apenas II e III

Acredito que a alternativa correta seria a B. Mas não tenho certeza, e se sim, por que seria?

Comment: AWS!? Ou você quis dizer AWT?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/package-summary.html

Comment: Então... Foi o que pensei tbm. Mas na questão veio AWS. No caso, se for pra ser AWT seria a alternativa B?

Comment: Além disso, os componentes do AWT são dinossauros que desde o lançamento do Java 1.2 em 1998 não deveriam ser usados para mais nada, sendo considerados obsoletos e tendo sido desde então substituídos pelos componentes do Swing. Me assusta o fato de alguém cobrar esse tipo de coisa em uma prova.

Comment: Sim, porque não existe componente `Windows`, e sim `Window`.

Comment: Obrigado Mano!!!

Comment: Aproveitando o post...

Comment: Em qualquer aplicação em que as ações do usuário devem ser interpretadas quando o mesmo interagir com a janela (Clicar num botão, mover o mouse, por exemplo) é necessário?

A - Modificar as propriedades de um JButton
B - Criar uma classe JFrame
C - Configurar o modo como nosso form será exibido em nosso computador
D - Implementar uma interface Listener
E - Alterar a propriedade Label ao passar com o Mouse

Comment: D - Esse tipo de coisas você trata com `ActionListener`, `MouseListener`, etc.

Comment: Blz Mano,... Valeu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considerando que era para ser AWT ao invés de AWS, vejamos:

- Temos a classe [`java.awt.Panel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/Panel.html).
- Temos a classe [`java.awt.Label`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/Label.html).
- Temos a classe [`java.awt.Window`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html). Observe que a grafia correta é `Window`, e não `Windows`.
- Temos a classe [`java.awt.Checkbox`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/Checkbox.html).
- Temos a classe [`java.awt.TextField`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/TextField.html).

Ou seja, as afirmações I, II, IV e V são verdadeiraas e a III é falsa. Logo, a alternativa correta é a B.

Faço uma observação que os componentes do AWT são dinossauros que desde o lançamento do Java 1.2 em 1998 não deveriam ser usados para mais nada, sendo considerados obsoletos e tendo sido desde então substituídos pelos componentes do Swing. Me assusta o fato de alguém cobrar esse tipo de coisa em uma prova.